# Specify different doctype based on browser type in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I would like to specify a different doc type based on the browser type. I want to specify

For Non - IE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

For IE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The reason being, the Report Viewer control is playing up in non-ie browsers with XHTML Strict doctype. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/7fc3a392-0aac-4772-9c50-22ba3bb7dc54?prof=required for more details.

Couldn't find a way to this from within the XHTML/ASPX file. I'm fiddling with DOTNET after a long time. Any hints would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add a literal control in place of the `<!DOCTYPE` tag in your aspx view - something like this: `<asp:literal id="DocType" runat="server"></asp:literal>`. Then, in your code-behind file, add code to detect the browser, and display the appropriate doctype tag:

```
   `Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.Browser.IsBrowser("IE") Then
        DocType.Text = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">"
    Else
        DocType.Text = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"">"
    End If
    End Sub`
```